# Example code for having a Grails Controller deal with a JSON request

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have been up and down the internet but I am having a devil of a time finding some simple sample code for making Grails process a JSON request.

Basically all I want is for someone to send me a JSON file and for me to be able to pass it to one of my business/domain classes to be worked with.  The JSON file can either come in as a simple text string or attached to a request object.  Just so long as I can pull the JSON out and parse it I suppose it doesn't matter.

I apologize, I'm a bit of a noob and I know the request is vague.  But is there a kind soul out there that can give me some example code to work with?  Just an example that shows how Grails should be used when receiving JSON request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails send request as JSON and parse it in controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270279/grails-send-request-as-json-and-parse-it-in-controller)

Comment: That particular question is trying to answer a very specific problem, I'm just asking for general example code because I can't seem to find any.  I've read that answer before, a couple times...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to have a controller method like:

```
def parse() { 
    println request.JSON
    def answer = [ status: 'ok' ]
    render answer as JSON
}
```

Then calling that from the command line (assuming it's in an application called json and a controller called `JsonRecieverController`):

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{ "username": "tim_yates", "answer": "true" }' \
     http://localhost:8080/json/jsonReciever/parse
```

Will print the `JsonObject`:

```
[username:tim_yates, answer:true]
```

And return

```
{"status":"ok"}
```

To `curl`

Comment: Thanks!  Concise and to the point, just what I was looking for!

Comment: What if you want to get the value of "username" in this case. When I do it like this `request.JSON.username` I get `[tim_yates]`. That is with the brackets.