# not able to get json data into controller, controller shows JSON request as null;

Tags: json, rest, grails, controller

I am trying to send JSON data into the controller, but controller prints it as null.

Below is the content of my controller code:

```
@Transactional
def save(User user) { 

    println "${request.JSON}"
    println "${request.JSON.owner}"
    println request.format
    user = new User(request.JSON)

    if (user == null) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        render status: NOT_FOUND
        return
    }

    if (user.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond user.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    user.save flush:true

    respond user, [status: CREATED, view:"show"]
}
```

I have tried everything given at this link [Grails send request as JSON and parse it in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270279/grails-send-request-as-json-and-parse-it-in-controller)

URL mappings:

```
 post "/user/"(controller: "user",parseRequest:true, action:"save")
```

When I try this:

```
curl --data '{"owner":"new owner"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/user/
```

I get output as:

```
{"message":"Property [owner] of class [class com.sample.User] cannot be null","path":"/user/index","_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/user/index"}}
```

This is the output from controller:

```
[:]
null
json
```

I created the app using rest-api profile,

Controller accepts "text/html" type for "POST" operation but not JSON
and I can update an existing object with JSON as content type.

My domain class has three fields

```
String owner
String category
Boolean deleted = false
```

I am using postman to send JSON requests.

```
{
    "owner":"some user",
    "category":"rule01"
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which grails version?

Comment: I am using grails 3.2.1

Comment: Post the dump of your `params`.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

Okay, we go little by little; try this URL in your browser

```
http://localhost:8080/user/save?owner=the+beautiful&category=homo+sapiens
```

with this code below,

```
@Transactional
def save() {     
    println params.owner
    println params.category

    render (params as JSON)
}
```

and post here, whatever you receive in the browser.

Comment: Tried this.. still getting as "null"

Comment: What's the output when you do `println params`?

Comment: I am getting "null" as output when i print

Comment: You mean there are no `params`. But in the question you posted, the output of `request.format`, `json`; isn't it?

Comment: yes, I am passing params from Postman. I am getting null for  `println params['owner']`  and   `println params['category']`

Comment: Yes, but then I asked you to try, `println params`. Do this and post the output.

Comment: This is the output for  `println params`  =  ` [controller:user, format:null]`  and when I tried this  `http://localhost:8080/user/save?owner=the+beautiful&category=homo+sapiens`  I get   `{"message":"Not Found","error":404}`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and after trying some guesses :) here is how I managed to resolve it.

## Json Request:

[image: json request]

## My controller:

```
 def postentry (accountno){

 def fulldata = request.reader.text
 def ddd =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(fulldata)
 accountno = ddd.accountno[0].toString()
 println accountno
 transidd = ddd.transid[0].toString()
 transamtt = ddd.transamt[0].toString()
 transtype = ddd.transtype[0]
 }
```

## For curl:

```
 POST /transact HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8080
 Content-Type: application/json
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Postman-Token: aa898872-e448-bace-9f6d-143bdc0b03db

 [{
 "accountno": 000710023005,
 "transid": 16,
 "transamt": 20.25,
 "transtype": "withdrawal"
 }]
```

I tried avoiding jsonSlurper in my controller but I just could not get my values without it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is from grails 3.x.x